# Retrieve all of the images from the server via Glide or Volley library and show them in list view

Tags: android, eclipse, server

I want to Retrieve all of the images from the server via Glide or Volley library and show them in list view. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do the image management. Glide can do it internally for you.

For `ListView`, use glide to load the image in `getView()` method of the adapter

For `Recyclerview`, use glide to load the image in `onBindViewHolder()` method of `Adapter`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to Retrieve all of the images from the server via Glide or
>   Volley library

Those libraries are used to ***loading & caching images*** on Android actually.

In order to download and show all of those images, you can make a `Json` output of all those links from server side by using `json_encode()` (*on PHP for example*) then [parse the json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-do-i-parse-json-in-android) in Android and loop through the whole `Json` output of links then show the images by [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Volley](https://github.com/google/volley) library.

**Edit**:

This is how it should be, on the Android(Client side) inside `RecyclerView` `Adapter`:

```
Glide.with(myContext)
                    .load(mPosts.imgurl)
                    .apply(options)
                    .into(ViewHolder.imgShow)
```

Follow: https://ledron.github.io/RecyclerView/

You can however add those links seperately inside an `ArrayList` on Android then showing those too. Follow the tutorial and use Adapter for `RecyclerView`.

Example `Adapter`:

```
public class Adapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>{

    ArrayList<String> urls;
    Context context;
    //constructor
    public Adapter(ArrayList<String> ImgUrl, Context context_)
    {
        this.urls = ImgUrl;
        this.context = context_;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        private ImageView image;

        public ViewHolder(View v)
        {
          super(v);
          image =(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.img);
        }

        public ImageView getImage(){ return this.image;}
    }

    @Override
    public Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
        v.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(1080,800));
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        Glide.with(this.context)
                .load(urls.get(position))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(holder.getImage());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return urls.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: Tnx, How I make a JSON output of all those links from the server side by using json_encode() (on PHP for example)? Can you tell me?

Comment: Just already told. You can make a list of URLs on the server side (Use Google) then use json_encode to give the json output. This is also related to another question and does not belong to this question. Please use Ask question for further questions.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm the beginner in android, I understand that I should "make a list of URLs on the server side (Use Google) then use json_encode to give the JSON output", but How do it? I want the code for it...

Comment: Is it a good question for asking: "In order to download and show all of the images, I want make a JSON output of all the links from server side by using json_encode() (on PHP for example) . tnx

Comment: @Mpi You can also add those links inside an `ArrayList` and showing them in the `RecyclerView` without being need to have the server side codes. But as you know, this is not a recommended way for the future links adding :) Check the updated answer.

Comment: Really? I will check it ... And I use eclipse for programming.

Comment: Yes, you can do that too. Use Android Studio. Eclipse is a depreciated IDE and fossil actually. However, like I said, **that's not a recommended way for the future links adding.**

Comment: Yes, I will change my IDE certainly, Okay, thanks. In this way that you said, Can I set an URL that shows the folder of my photos? for example www.example.com/photos

Answer (score 0):

**In Your Gradle**

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
}
```

**Load image into list**

```
  String url = myUrls.get(position);

  GlideApp
    .with(myFragment)
    .load(url)
    .centerCrop()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
    .into(myImageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a java class that `Extends ArrayAdapter<ImageView>` and use it for `ListView`:

```
class imageadapter extends ArrayAdapter<ImageView> {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private String[] imageurls;

    imageadapter(Context context, String[] imageurls) {
        super(context, R.layout.imagelayout);
        this.imageurls = imageurls;
        this.context = context;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }


    @SuppressLint({"ViewHolder", "SetTextI18n", "ClickableViewAccessibility"})
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View layout = convertView;
        Holder holder = null;
        if (layout == null) {
            layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagelayout, parent, false);
            holder = new Holder();
            holder.imageView1 = layout.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            holder.textView1 = layout.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            layout.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) layout.getTag();
        }

        Picasso.get().load(imageurls[position]).fit().into(holder.imageView1);
        holder.textView1.setText("Image:" + (position + 1));

        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageurls.length;
    }


    static class Holder {

        ImageView imageView1;
        TextView textView1;

    }

}
```